# BitcoinCore wallet still 3 years in sync, funds in account

Tags: bitcoin-core

I use bitcoin core and the thing is still syncing after a week and a bit.
I received btc into the account and the transaction was confirmed over 150 times.
Can I move these funds to another wallet with the wallet.dat or is there any alternative or something I can do besides sitting through this sync process? Is there any one I can contact about this? I don't think my computer has 140gb spare space :L.

Answer (score 1):

In order to operate your bitcoins you need two things, your public and private key for your BTC address. You can export them from the bitcoin core wallet.

There is two types of wallets - ones that require you to download the whole blockchain locally and others that uses someone else server to run checks on the blockchain.

Here is list with wallets https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet

You can use Electrum to import your keys and use them right away without waiting for sync.